# Restore menubar after exiting full screen NSView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, fullscreen, nsview

I am setting an NSView in fullscreen mode and I hide the menubar without problem. My issue is when exiting fullscreen mode. How can I restore the menubar? I tried with and without options but result remains the same: menubar is missing:

```
func exitFullScreen()  {
    let presOptions: NSApplication.PresentationOptions = [.hideDock, .hideMenuBar]
    let optionsDictionary = [NSView.FullScreenModeOptionKey.fullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions: NSNumber(value: presOptions.rawValue), NSView.FullScreenModeOptionKey.fullScreenModeAllScreens: false]
    presentationWindowController.window?.contentView?.exitFullScreenMode(options: optionsDictionary)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just needed to set the app presentation options again:

```
 NSApplication.shared.presentationOptions = []
```